# Can't Change message size limit in postfix?

Tags: postfix

```
postconf -d | grep message_size_limit
```

Shows:

```
message_size_limit = 10240000
```

This limit was not set in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` so I assume its a default?

I added `message_size_limit = 31457280` to my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and restarted postfix. But I still get `message_size_limit = 10240000` from `postconf -d | grep message_size_limit`. It's not accepting my change. why?

Comment: Try do hard reload using `/etc/init.d.postfix stop ; /etc/init.d/postfix start`. You can try to check, if postfix use the same config file by `postconf | grep config_directory`

Comment: The config directory is correct, stopping and starting manually has no change (its `service postfix stop` on this system), no errors in mail log.

Comment: What's particularly weird about this to me is the number "10240000".  Is that supposed to be 10MB? I guess it should be either "10485760" or "10000000" but the default setting appears to be some kind of mixed bag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `man postconf`:

```
-d    Print default parameter settings instead of actual settings.
```

You have do not use `-d` parameter in the invocation of `postconf` utility.

Comment: In other words, I'm an idiot.

Comment: No, but sometimes people don't see everythink, me is one of them.

Comment: Holy sh*t. Joining the idiots club. :/

Answer (score 0):

You should not check that with the -d option, it gives the default value. Check like this:

```
[root@linuxportalmail postfix]# postconf |grep size_limit
body_checks_size_limit = 51200
bounce_size_limit = 50000
header_size_limit = 102400
mailbox_size_limit = 512000000
message_size_limit = 25600000
```

Greetings,

Paul Mostertman